# Use timestamp with or without time zone in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

## Use timestamp with or without time zone in Postgres?

The web app will be used in different countries, therefore i'll have to deal with different timestamps. The system has several data input of different objects which have their own insert/update date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS). This is so the supervisor can verify if something was done after office hours.

### Example

If a object is inserted at 03:00 AM at Italy, that object visualized in Brazil should also show 03:00 AM.

To complement, the backend is PHP, database Postgres, and javascript & jQuery in the frontend.

**What should I use in database, timestamp with or without timezone? and/or UTC? *Why?***

Answer (score 1):

If your use case for the discussed entries is **only** "check office hours" you can use timestamp without time zone and be happy, no conversion.

If you will also need to know the exact sequence of actions you should use timestamp with time zone and have the time zone of the user available somewhere in your data.

I would use timestamptz. Please note that postgresql lets convert to and from time zones in SQL [see here section 9.9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: The main reason is for showing the same hour something happened, no matter in what country you're on. What should I do in this case?